# Incorrect value for sum of two NSIntegers

Tags: iphone, nsinteger

I'm sure I'm missing something and the answer is very simple, but I can't seem to understand why this is happening. I'm trying to make an average of dates:

```
NSInteger runningSum =0;
NSInteger count=0;
for (EventoData *event in self.events) {
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    if (event.date != nil) {
        dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:event.date];
        runningSum += (NSInteger)[dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970];
        count += 1;
    }
}
if (count>0) {
    NSLog(@"average is: %@",[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSInteger)((CGFloat)runningAverage/count)]);
}
```

Everything seems to work OK, except for runningSum += (NSInteger)[dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970], which gives an incorrect result. If I put a breakpoint when taking the average of two equal dates (2009-10-10, for example, which is a timeInterval of 1255125600), runningSum is -1784716096, instead of the expected 2510251200.

I've tried using NSNumber and I get the same result. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Antonio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason you are fudging about with NSInteger?

[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970] returns an NSTimeInterval, which is basically a double. Clean up the code and see if that helps.

Comment: Doh! sorry, I feel sheepish now. Changed everything to float and works beautifully.

Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger can hold values up to the `INT_MAX` limit that equals 2147483647 - so your value overflows the integer types limit - remember that timeInterval is a double type.

You can try to use double type in all your calculations or use `-timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` method - it returns interval since `1 January 2001` and you might avoid overflow as well.

If your `events` object is an array or other type that allows to get its size then you can add time interval values already divided by count - that also may help to avoid overflow:

```
NSTimeInterval runningSum = 0;
NSInteger count = [self.events count];
for (...){
...
runningSum += [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970]/count;
}
```

Comment: true, thanks. Changed everything to float. This is what happens when you don't take a step back.

Answer (score 0):

`NSInteger` is a 32 bit signed integer on iPhone and is therefore limited to values between −2147483648 and +2147483647.

You may get the desired result by using `NSUInteger` which is an unsigned 32 bit integer able to contain values between 0 and +4294967295.

You should however pay attention to the number of runs through the loop so you don't wrap the values.